# Android HashSet cannot be cast to LinkedHashSet

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, hashset, linkedhashset

I've the following sample code. The application is installed successfully at first time.
However, it throws an error on reinstalling.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinkedHashSet<String> planets = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
        planets.add("Earth");
        SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(0);
        prefs.edit().putStringSet("planets", planets).commit();
        prefs = getPreferences(0);
        planets = (LinkedHashSet<String>) prefs.getStringSet("planets", new  LinkedHashSet<String>());
    }
}
```

I've pasted the error produced on reinstalling the application below.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashSet cannot be cast to java.util.LinkedHashSet at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
```

I want to understand why a saved `LinkedHashSet` can not be casted back to `LinkedHashSet`. And why is it automaically being converted to `HashSet` by Android?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@Ibungo, I think you've misunderstood what `SharedPreferences` do.
You can NOT ask the prefs to save a `LinkedHashSet` set - you can only ask it to save a general `Set`. And in return you can get a general `Set` after that. There are no guarantees that it'll return the same set implementation as yours.

The preferences are just iterating over the set of items you gave them and writing them to the XML store for your application. Thus when you ask for those items it is reading from the XML and creating a new Set - `HashSet` since it is the most commonly used one.

The only reason you might want a `LinkedHashSet`, I can think of, is if you want to preserve the insertion order. If this is the case, you might try converting your collection to ArrayList and store it - there is an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11050845/964626). Alternatively you could save your data to a `JSONArray` and store it as a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to use a basic `HashSet`:

```
HashSet<String> planets = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
planets.add("Earth");
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(0);
prefs.edit().putStringSet("planets", planets).commit();
prefs = getPreferences(0);
planets = prefs.getStringSet("planets", new  LinkedHashSet<String>());
```

Side note: Keep in mind that `SharedPreferences.getStringSet()` is available in API11+ only.

The reason why your `Set` is converted to a `HashSet` can be found in [Android's source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/jb-mr2-release/core/java/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java#L316):

```
public Editor putStringSet(String key, Set<String> values) {
    synchronized (this) {
        mModified.put(key,
            (values == null) ? null : new HashSet<String>(values));
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @flx, I want to know why I can't use LinkedHashSet.

Comment: Because `SharedPreferences.getStringSet()` is returning a `HashSet`, not a `LinkedHashSet`. It's that simple.

Comment: But why? I'm asking it to save a `LinkedHashSet`, so why does it return me `HashSet`?

Comment: You didn't. You asked it to save a `HashSet`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#putStringSet(java.lang.String, java.util.Set<java.lang.String>) // you can not change the signature of a API method with your plain imagination.

Comment: Hi @flx, as per Android API we can pass any class's object which implements the `Set` interface. Both `HashSet` and `LinkedHashSet` implement `Set` interface, and as per OP's code, he is asking API to save a `LinkedHashSet`. So why is it automatically being converted to `HashSet` when he is trying to get the same object back? Full disclosure: I'm OP's colleague.

Comment: Because the underlying API is serializing the `Set` and later it is deserializing it to a `HashSet`. Here is the line of the Android API which converts your `Set` into a `HashSet`: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/jb-mr2-release/core/java/android/app/SharedPreferencesImpl.java#L316

Comment: still not satisfied with the answer?

Comment: This makes sense now. Specially after @SamuilYanovski's answer and your link to the source code.